# How to modify StartupPath through Pythonnet

Tags: python, c#, ironpython, python.net

I have a bundle of C# DLLs that I am trying to wrap with python using the *pythonnet* library.

I noticed that the DLLs are using **Application.StartupPath**, which in python's case is where the python.exe is located (as far as I understand). This is problematic for me, since it means that I need to copy all the DLLs to the folder where python is being installed (o/w the DLLs raise an exception). If I understand correctly, **Application.StartupPath** cannot be modified using the *pythonnet* library. Also, I do not have any access to the DLLs source code, but I know that they are using **Application.StartupPath** (because I used *dotPeak*). Building the DLLs from scratch is not a possibility either, since the build is very complicated and requires lots of dependencies.

I'll be glad if someone can help me understand how I can avoid copying the DLLs folder contents to my python interpreter's path.

Comment: To modify the behavior of Application.StartupPath in C#, you can set the AppDomain.BaseDirectory property to the path of your choice. This property returns the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies.